# getting name value of clicked on class element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying the following but it keeps getting the first name value of the first element with the class "button-blue". How can I work correctly so that it gets the name value of the element clicked on with this class??

```
$(".button-blue").click(function() {

    alert($(".button-blue").attr('name'));

});
```

Comment: You have to understand how Jq selectors work. When you use `$(".someClass")` you are getting **all** elements which have that class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `this.name` instead. Inside an event handler, `this` is the DOM element on which the event was triggered.

If you prefer to use `.attr()` or need a jQuery object containing that element for another reason, you can simply use `$(this).attr('name')`

Answer (score 0):

Inside an event handler, this.tagName should give you the name.